# Can't trigger dropzone emit method

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone as a jquery plugin so I haven't instantiated using.

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", { url: "/file/post"});
```

I've used this method.

```
$("div#myId").dropzone({ url: "/file/post" });
```

But I need to do this:

```
myDropzone.emit("addedfile", jsonFile);
```

I've tried

```
$("div#myId").emit("addedfile", jsonFile);
```

and i've tried

```
var myDropzone= $("div#myId").dropzone({ url: "/file/post" });

myDropzone.emit("addedfile", jsonFile);
```

I feel like this is some basic hole in my understanding of how these things work so an explanation of my error would also be much appreciated.

Many Thanks,

Paul

Comment: There was only one, I've fixed that now. There were quite a few when I submitted as I was on flaky ios connection but I edited it immediately. Did you make this comment immediately it was posted? I can't see any more.

Comment: Sure that looks better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Dropzone.forElement("div#myId").emit("addedfile", jsonFile);`

Comment: thanks for your reply, when I do this: `Dropzone.forElement("#myId").emit("addedfile", jsonFile);`  
I get : TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object. Any ideas?

Comment: Try assigning the dropzone element to an object first: `var myDropzone = Dropzone.forElement("myId");` Then use the console log to see if it is assigning it properly, then work from there.

Comment: sorry for delay coming back to this, I will be looking at it again so I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I created a function like so:

```
function foo(dz) {
    var jsonFile = {name: 'moo', size: 10}
    dz.emit('addedfile', jsonFile)
}
```

And called it like this:

```
$('#mydrop').dropzone({
  url: '/foo/bar',
  init: function() {
    var dz = this
    foo(dz)
  }
})
```

And then I was able to emit events from within foo()

Have a look at [enyo's comment on jQuery instancing: Accessing Dropzone object](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/180#issuecomment-19875928).